# Как убрать перенос строки в TextArea после нажатии кнопки Enter

Tags: java, javafx

Как можно отменить перенос строки после нажатия кнопки Enter? Пробовал через textArea.clear(), но это не помогло. В гугле так же не нашел решения. Вот что я имею:

```
textArea.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                button.fire();
                textArea.clear();
            }
        });
```

---

Вопрос  решен!  Тема  закрыта.

Comment: Может, стоит удалить последний символ строки? Или как там enter отображается

Comment: может поможет `event.consume()`

Comment: @AndreyM, спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @AndreyM как ответ оформите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы прервать распространение события в цепочке обработки используйте [`event.consume`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--)

```
textArea.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
        button.fire();
        textArea.clear();
        event.consume(); 
    }
});
```